Role of the natural temperature scale in the anomalous dimension of the renormalization group
In David Tong's lecture notes on statistical field theory, the concept of anomalous dimensions is introduced by considering the scaling of the correlation function $$\langle \phi(\mathbf{x}) \phi(\mathbf{0}) \rangle \sim \frac{1}{r^{d - 2 + \eta}},\tag{3.8}$$ for fields $\phi(\mathbf{x})$, near a fixed point in the renormalization group flow. This does not match the engineering dimension $\sim 1/r^{d-2}$ as would be expected from dimensional analysis, so it is then reasoned that there must be an additional length scale $a$ in the problem which comes from short-range physics, and amends the scaling relation as $$\langle \phi(\mathbf{x}) \phi(\mathbf{0}) \rangle \sim \frac{a^{\eta}}{r^{d - 2 + \eta}}.\tag{p.63}$$
Here is my question. Earlier on p.54 in the same lecture notes the choice was made to absorb the factor $\beta \sim 1/T$ into the definition of $\phi$. However, $\beta$ is a dimensionful parameter, with an associated natural length scale that arises from the temperature. So why could we not use $\beta$ to "fix" the anomalous dimension, instead of the short-range scale $a$? Specifically I am wondering why I cannot write this: $$\langle \phi(\mathbf{x}) \phi(\mathbf{0}) \rangle \sim \frac{\beta^{\eta/2}}{r^{d - 2 + \eta}}$$ Since $\beta$ has dimension of length squared, this form will still obey dimensional analysis, yet there was no need to reference the short-range scale $a$. Why can I not do this? Is there some assumption about the temperature scale in the systems of interest that I have missed?
Edit: Having thought about it more, I think I can make my question more focused. My suggestion to fix the anomalous dimension by including powers of $\beta$ is actually too restrictive. In the Ising model for example, there is also the exchange energy $J$, which could have been similarly multiplied with $\langle \phi(\mathbf{x}) \phi(\mathbf{0}) \rangle$ to allow for different powers in $r$.
The crux of my question then is as follows. If the correlation function has units $1/L^{d-2}$, then why does that necessarily imply that $\langle \phi(\mathbf{x}) \phi(\mathbf{0}) \rangle \sim 1/ r^{d-2}$, when I could always multiply the right hand side with some dimensionful parameter like $\beta$ or $J$, to then get a different power law in $r$?

The usual rule $\langle\phi(x)\phi(0)\rangle\sim 1/x^{2\Delta}$ holds in $\mathbb R^d$. If the manifold has a single scale, such as $S^1\times\mathbb R^{d-1}$, this scaling is still valid, since we cannot construct a dimensionless parameter out of the radius of $S^1$ only. But if the manifold has multiple scales, such as $S^1\times S^1\times\mathbb R^{d-2}$, then the rule $\langle\phi(x)\phi(0)\rangle\sim 1/x^{2\Delta}$ is no longer valid, since we can shift it by an arbitrary function of $f(R_1/R_2)$ without messing up dimensional analysis. This is indeed what happens on the torus, for example, where typical 2-point functions are complicated functions of $q=e^{2\pi i\tau}$, with $\tau\sim R_1/R_2$ is the complex structure.
Temperature is just the radius of the time-like circle so this discussion holds. If the spatial manifold has no scales, such as $\mathbb R^{d-1}$, then the 2-point function takes the form $\langle\phi(x)\phi(0)\rangle\sim 1/x^{2\Delta}$. This easily follows from the Ward identity associated to dilations. If the spatial manifold has one or more scales, this simple scaling is no longer true, and you have to work harder.
But, to be clear, the answer $\langle\phi(x)\phi(0)\rangle\sim 1/x^{2\Delta}$ is not just dimensional analysis. It is the result of scale invariance. If you could do just dimensional analysis, you would conclude that this result is true in any QFT, which is definitely not the case. In order to show that this 2-point function takes this form, you need to use a Ward identity.

At the fixed point there can be no characteristic scale (e.g. $\beta$ or $J$ as you suggest) in the problem. Otherwise, the RG flow rescaling would alter these scales, which definitionally cannot happen at a fixed point (Tong mentions this around p. 59). So, the only length scale in the game is the distance $r$, and (as you mentioned) the short-distance cutoff $a$.

Yes I understand, but $\beta$ and $J$ are still dimensional quantities, which I can use to rescale the fields $\phi$, as Tong also does on P. 54. Then I would logically get a different dimensional analysis, yet the scaling with $r$ obviously does not change.
